# XSL Getting the last node of a selection

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file containing images data:

```
<images>
<aid>1</aid>
  <imid>1</imid>
    <src>img1.jpg</src>
</images>
<images>
<aid>1</aid>
  <imid>2</imid>
    <src>img2.jpg</src>
</images>
<images>
<aid>1</aid>
  <imid>3</imid>
    <src>img3.jpg</src>
</images>
<images>
<aid>2</aid>
  <imid>1</imid>
    <src>img1.jpg</src>
</images>
<images>
<aid>2</aid>
  <imid>2</imid>
    <src>img2.jpg</src>
</images>
<images>
etc...
```

I would like to get from every **aid** only the last **imid**
and present it as result, in this example case it would be:
aid=1 and imid=3 and src=img3.jpg
aid=2 and imid=2 and src=img2.jpg

*(In the original file, an **aid** can contains a lot of **imid**'s)*

The following xsl selection will give me only the last image from the complete selection of all the images.

```
<xsl:for-each select="(/images[aid&gt;=1 and imid])[last()]">
```

The following xsl selection gave me a result of every first **imid** in the **aid**.

```
<xsl:for-each select="(/images[aid&gt;=1 and imid=1])">
```

How can I adjusted that code, so it will give me only the last **imid** of every **aid**?

Comment: You say you want the last `imid` from every `aid`, but that's not how your source XML is formed. You might want to take another look at your input or fix your example.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//images" group-by="aid">
  <xsl:variable name="last" select="current-group()[last()]"/>
  <out aid="{$last/aid}" imid="{$last/imid}" src="{$last/src}"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:key name="kImagesByAid" match="images" use="aid">
<xsl:variable name="vLastImids" 
     select="/*/images[count(.|key('kImageByAid',aid)[last()])=1]/imid"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kImgByAid" match="images" use="aid"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "images[not(generate-id()
             =generate-id(key('kImgByAid',aid)[last()])
             )
          ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped in a top element to be well-formed):

```
<gallery>
    <images>
        <aid>1</aid>
        <imid>1</imid>
        <src>img1.jpg</src>
    </images>
    <images>
        <aid>1</aid>
        <imid>2</imid>
        <src>img2.jpg</src>
    </images>
    <images>
        <aid>1</aid>
        <imid>3</imid>
        <src>img3.jpg</src>
    </images>
    <images>
        <aid>2</aid>
        <imid>1</imid>
        <src>img1.jpg</src>
    </images>
    <images>
        <aid>2</aid>
        <imid>2</imid>
        <src>img2.jpg</src>
    </images>
</gallery>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<gallery>
  <images>
    <aid>1</aid>
    <imid>3</imid>
    <src>img3.jpg</src>
  </images>
  <images>
    <aid>2</aid>
    <imid>2</imid>
    <src>img2.jpg</src>
  </images>
</gallery>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule (template) copies every node "as-is".
2. There is a single ovverriding template that excludes any `images` element that is not the last in its group.
3. Grouping is implemented using the classic Muenchian method.